# SQL Server 2008 R2: Only and only in condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table with two fields:

```
create table teste_r
(
colx varchar(10),
coly varchar(10)
);
```

Insertion of records:

```
insert into teste_r values('3','A'),('3','B'),('3','C')
                        ,('2','A'),('2','A'),('2','C')
                        ,('1','A'),('1','D');
```

**Note**: Now I want to show the `colx` which is belongs to only and only `A and C`.

So the according to the requirements the expected result should be:

**Expected Result**:

```
 colx    
 -----
 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT coly)` like this

```
SELECT colx
FROM teste_r r
WHERE r.coly IN('A','C')
GROUP BY colx
HAVING COUNT(distinct coly) = (SELECT COUNT(distinct coly) FROM teste_r r2 WHERE r2.colx = r.colx)
AND COUNT(distinct coly) = 2
```

This is an example of Relational Division with no Remainder. You can get more info in this [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) which is written by Joe Celko.

You can also look at this [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/) by Dwain Camps

Comment: Please check your script by adding 2 more records into table. 'Insert into teste_r values('4','A'),('5','C')';

Answer (score 1):

This query will results like you wish:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tr.colx
FROM dbo.teste_r AS tr
WHERE tr.colx IN (SELECT tr2.colx FROM dbo.teste_r AS tr2 WHERE tr2.coly IN ('A', 'C'))
    AND tr.colx NOT IN (SELECT tr2.colx FROM dbo.teste_r AS tr2 WHERE tr2.coly NOT IN ('A', 'C'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.colx
from teste_r t
where t.coly IN('A','C')
  and not exists ( select * 
                   from teste_r
                   where colx = t.colx
                     and coly not in ('A', 'C'))
group by t.colx
having count(distinct t.coly) = 2
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bdaa4/4)

Comment: Please check your script by adding 2 more records into table. 'Insert into teste_r values('4','A'),('5','C')';

Answer (score 0):

```
select  DISTINCT a.colx
from    teste_r a,
        teste_r b
WHERE   a.colx = b.colx
AND     ((a.coly = 'A' AND b.coly = 'C') OR (a.coly = 'C' AND b.coly = 'A'))
```

Comment: This query gives 3 also.

Comment: hmm yes i got confused at the only and only a and c part and thought the fact that only 2 is what the answer should be was a mistake lol... fixing it...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT colx FROM teste_r
GROUP BY colx
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN coly NOT IN('A','C') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=0 AND COUNT(DISTINCT coly)=2
```